# Small SQL issue. I have multiple 100 row tables. What is the SQL I need?

Tags: sql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

So I have two tables, 'clients' (200 rows) and 'services' (100 rows).

'Services' has a foreign key for client_id which references clients.id.

How can I pull out a list of all my client and their services, including clients who have no services?  How many rows will come out as a result of this query?

Much obliged, I am a noob for SQL with my simple Rails App.

Also: How could I use ActiveRecord query interface to get the same list as in the above question?

Answer (score 0):

The query would look something like this:

```
select *
from clients a 
-- to ensure you get the clients that have no service we use a left join
left join services b on a.id = b.id
-- optional conditions here (can leave the last part if there are no additional conditions:
where something = somethingelse
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick query that will join the two tables and return all clients and their services, if they have any:

```
select clients.client_name,
       services.service_name

from clients
left outer join services on clients.client_id = services.client_id
```